# Javascript click on each input get value from it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code

```
<div class="control">
    <input type="button" value="big" />
    <input type="button" value="blink" />
    <input type="button" value="bold" />
    <input type="button" value="fixed" />
    <input type="button" value="italics" />
    <input type="button" value="small" />
    <input type="button" value="strike" />
    <input type="button" value="sub" />
    <input type="button" value="sup" />
</div>
```

Then I want to get value from each input when click on it. The problem is that I don't know how to write it in javascript.
If in jQuery something like this:

```
$('.control input[type=button]').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

How can I convert the code above to javascript?

Comment: `control` is a class so use the class selector `('.control input[type=button]'`

Comment: And what's the issue you are having with the plain JS solution? Please post what you have. Do you have problems selecting the elements? Binding the event handler? Getting the value of the element?

Comment: I have problem with getting value of the each element when click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like ...

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.control input[type=button]');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
   buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I got it now

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.control input[type="button"]');

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{       

     inputs[i].onclick = function()
    {
      console.log(this.value);
    }


}
```

Comment: How can I trigger with this?